# I am importing a CSV File in pandas but the column is importing as multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import a csv file in colab but the first column is treated as multiindex instead of data. Please help. I am attaching an image.
[Attached-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1DmN.png)

So instead of the first and second columns that contains IP-addresses being imported as data, they are imported as multiindex.
How can I remove this ?

Edit: There is no header in my CSV file !!

Comment: Is your file actually comma-separated, as you have promised pandas it is?

Comment: Try use `index_col=False` instead of `index_col=None`

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, It is a CSV file. But it was not in proper format like for some rows only 3 values were available instead of 5. I guess that's why pandas were having trouble processing it.

Comment: @RoryLM Your solution worked. Thank you soo much !!